# Replace part of class name via jquery based on active class

Tags: jquery, class, replace, classname

I have a ul menu with three li classes: .1-is-on, .2-is-off, .3-is-off.

Whichever li with the class .active, should show the "on" part of the class name. By default on page load, 1-is-on has .active assigned to it. When I click on 2-is-off .active moves to 2-is-off and leaves 1-is-on, which is great.

As the .active just moved, I want the li where .active is on now to do two things:
1. Replace the "off" part with "on"
2. Replace other "on" from sibling li's with "off"

jQuery:

```
$(function() {    
$("ul.menu li").bind('click',function() {
   var xxx = $(this).siblings('li:not(.active)')
       if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).attr("class",this.className.replace('off','on'));
        $(xxx).attr("class",xxx.className.replace('on','off'));
        }
});
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="1-is-on active">1</li>
    <li class="2-is-off">2</li>
    <li class="3-is-off">3</li>
</ul>
```

I hope it's just something small I missed but it's driving me crazy!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("ul.menu li").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().each(function() {
       this.className = this.className.replace("on", "off"); 
    });
    this.className = this.className.replace("off", "on");
    $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
});
```

This replaces `on` with `off` for all the siblings of the clicked element, then replaces `off` with `on` for the clicked element. It then adds the `active` class to the clicked element and removes it from all others.

You can see an example of this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/r3ELy/1/).

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {    
    $("ul.menu li").bind('click',function() {
        // Do nothing if we're already active...
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) return;

        // find the previously active element, remove active and remove "on"
        var previousOn = $(this).siblings('.active');
        previousOn.removeClass('active');
        previousOn.attr("class", previousOn.attr("class").replace("on", "off"));

        // Make the current element active
        $(this).addClass('active');
        // Replace "off" with "on" for this element
        this.className = this.className.replace('off','on');
    });
});
```

Comment: You're missing the closing parenthesis and semi-colon on the line beginning `previousOn.attr(...` (and a few other semi-colons).

Comment: @james Thanks for that. The semicolons are meh (optional) but the parenthesis would have not been!